# How i upload blob image into my product table?

Tags: php, image, blob

I have tried many ways to let my selected image uploaded into my product table  but nothing happened no errors occurred here is my php code and form

```
    <?php



    //connect to the server and create database.
    $host = "localhost";
                        $userMS = "";
                        $passwordMS = "";
                        $connection = mysql_connect($host,$userMS,$passwordMS) or die("Couldn't  connect:".mysql_error());
                        $database = "projectDataBase";
                        $db = mysql_select_db($database,$connection) or die("Couldn't select database");


    //three pages one for form and anthor one for the search page.

            /*if (isset($_POST['sSearch']))
            {

                processForm();
        }*/


        if (isset($_POST['sAddProduct']))
        {

            addNewProduct();
        }

            else if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

                addNewImage();
            }

            else if(isset($_POST['delete']))
        {
        $Product_ID=$_POST['Product_ID'];
        $mysqlquery="delete  from Product where Product_ID= ".$Product_ID."";
        mysql_query($mysqlquery);
            echo "Deleted successfully";
            echo("<FORM><INPUT Type='button' VALUE='Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'></FORM>");
        }
        else
            //hasn't yet been submitted, display the form
        {
            showForm();
        }

function addNewProduct()
{
        $ProductName = $_POST['Product_Name'];
        $ProductPrice = $_POST['Price'];


        //database query to add country
        $insertStringProduct = "INSERT into Product(Product_Name, Price)
        VALUE('$ProductName', '$ProductPrice')" ;
        $result = mysql_query($insertStringProduct);
        echo ("<p1>Product added Successfully</p1>");
        echo("<FORM><INPUT Type='button' VALUE='Back' onClick='history.go(-1);return true;'></FORM>");




}


///////>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Here what i added but nothing happened<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
function addNewImage(){

    $image = $_POST['Image'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product
    (Image)
    VALUE
    ( '$image')" echo "Please Upload an image..";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("error in uploading/*");

}
```

this is the form i used :

Here is my database product table where you could find image row 
http://www.ya-techno.com/up/uploads/1429085907261.png

Answer (score 0):

Please check i have updated the function:

```
function addNewImage(){

    $image = $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Image']['tmp_name']));
    $sql = "INSERT INTO product(Image) VALUES ('".$image."')";
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die("error in uploading/*");

}
```

try to change the function like this and you also need to store the file extension.It will help in fetching the file  from database and also you need to use PDO.

and your form should be like this:

```
<form action='form.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> <input type='file' name='Image'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>
</from>
```

Comment: not working whats 'tmp_name' ?i haven't got this into my product table

Comment: please try to echo $image and also send the code of your form.

Comment: this is my image form <from action='forms.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'> <input type='file' name='Image'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong here:

`$image = $_FILES['Image']` instead of `$_POST['Image']`

Then try following:

```
$image = mysql_escape_string(file_get_contents($image['tmp_name']));
```

Pass this variable as you are already doing. `mysql_escape_string` will make it more accurate and precise.

Comment: this is my image form                                                                                      <from action='forms.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type='file' name='Image'> <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>

Comment: it should be `<form>` instead of `<from>`. Also, please ensure your form is also getting closed like: `</form>` because I don't find it in your comment.